# How can I draw colorful Emoji in Java Graphics2D?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am trying to render text in LWJGL(Minecraft), but i got some problem.
I am trying to draw colorful emoji in Java Graphics2D, but it can't work normally.
You can see, the Graphics2D draw a black and white character.

My final goal is render Emoji in LWJGL(Minecraft).
If you want more infomation, you can tell me.

[Imgur Drawing Bed](https://i.bmp.ovh/imgs/2022/02/b9793771f5ca1c7f.png)
[China Drawing Bed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u2I4.png)

Key Source Code:

```
public BufferedImage createCharImage(int cp){
        Objects.requireNonNull(this.font);
        Objects.requireNonNull(this.fontMetrics);

        int charWidth = this.fontMetrics.charWidth(cp);
        int charHeight = this.fontMetrics.getHeight();

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(charWidth, charHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();

        if(this.antiAlias){
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        }

        g.setFont(this.font);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(Character.toChars(cp)), 0, this.fontMetrics.getAscent());
        g.dispose();
        return image;
    }
```

Full Source Code:

```
    private final Font font;
    private FontMetrics fontMetrics;
    private boolean antiAlias;
    private boolean lineWrap;

    public FontRenderer(Font font){
        Objects.requireNonNull(font);

        this.font = font;
        this.antiAlias = true;
        this.lineWrap = true;

        initFontRenderer();
    }

    public FontRenderer(File fontFile, int size){
        Objects.requireNonNull(fontFile);

        this.font = FontUtils.readFontFromTTF(fontFile, size);
        this.antiAlias = true;
        this.lineWrap = true;

        initFontRenderer();
    }

    public Font getFont(){
        return this.font;
    }

    public void setAntiAlias(boolean antiAlias){
        this.antiAlias = antiAlias;
    }

    public void setLineWrap(boolean lineWrap){
        this.lineWrap = lineWrap;
    }

    private void initFontRenderer(){
        this.initFontMetrics();
        // Reject HardCode!
    }

    private void initFontMetrics(){
        Objects.requireNonNull(this.font);
        // TYPE_INT_ARGB
        // TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        
        // Anti Alias
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setFont(this.font);
        this.fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();

        g.dispose();
    }

    public BufferedImage createCharImage(int cp){
        Objects.requireNonNull(this.font);
        Objects.requireNonNull(this.fontMetrics);

        int charWidth = this.fontMetrics.charWidth(cp);
        int charHeight = this.fontMetrics.getHeight();

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(charWidth, charHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();

        if(this.antiAlias){
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        }

        g.setFont(this.font);
        g.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(Character.toChars(cp)), 0, this.fontMetrics.getAscent());
        g.dispose();
        return image;
    }

    private HashMap<Integer, CharTexture> textureMap;

    public void drawString(String s, double x, double y){
        if(textureMap == null){
            textureMap = new HashMap<Integer, CharTexture>();
        }

        double lineWidth = 0;
        double lineHeight = this.fontMetrics.getHeight();
        double linesHeight = 0;

        int cplength = s.codePointCount(0, s.length());
        for(int i = 0; i < cplength; i++){
            int cpi = s.offsetByCodePoints(0, i);
            int cp = s.codePointAt(cpi);

            String cps = String.valueOf(Character.toChars(cp));

            if(cps == "\n"){/*1*/
                lineWidth = 0;
                linesHeight += lineHeight;
            }else{/*1*/
                CharTexture texture;

                if(textureMap.containsKey(cp)){
                    texture = textureMap.get(cp);
                }else{
                    
                    BufferedImage image = this.createCharImage(cp);
                    int width = image.getWidth();
                    int height = image.getHeight();
                    int textureId = RenderUtils.uploadTextureImage(image);

                    texture = new CharTexture(width, height, textureId);

                    textureMap.put(cp, texture);
                }

                // render
                RenderUtils.drawImage(
                    texture.textureId, 
                    (x + lineWidth), 
                    (y + linesHeight), 
                    (x + lineWidth + texture.width), 
                    (y + linesHeight + texture.height)
                );

                lineWidth += texture.width;
            }/*1*/
        }
    }
```

RenderUtils.java

```
    public static ByteBuffer readImageToBuffer(BufferedImage bufferedImage){
        
        int[] rgb = bufferedImage.getRGB(0, 0, bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), null, 0, bufferedImage.getWidth());
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * rgb.length);

        for(int i : rgb){
            byteBuffer.putInt(i << 8 | i >> 24 & 255);
        }
        byteBuffer.flip();
        return byteBuffer;
    }

    public static int uploadTextureImage(BufferedImage bufferedImage){
        int textureId = GL11.glGenTextures();
        // https://www.jianshu.com/p/1b327789220d
        // 纹理
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
        // 设置纹理包装和过滤的方式
        // GL_CLAMP_TP_EDGE 和 GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER 和 GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT会报错 1280: Invalid enum
        // May be because the enum is not available in this lwjgl

        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
        
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
        
        GL11.glTexImage2D(
            GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            GL11.GL_RGBA,
            bufferedImage.getWidth(),
            bufferedImage.getHeight(),
            0,
            GL11.GL_RGBA,
            GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            readImageToBuffer(bufferedImage)
        );

        return textureId;
    }

    public static void drawImage(int textureId, double x, double y, double x2, double y2) {

        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

        GL11.glTexCoord2d(1,0);
        GL11.glVertex2d(x2, y);
        GL11.glTexCoord2d(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2d(x, y);
        GL11.glTexCoord2d(0, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2d(x, y2);
        GL11.glTexCoord2d(1,1);
        GL11.glVertex2d(x2, y2);

        GL11.glEnd();

        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
```

Comment: The [Graphics2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) class has a `setColor` method that allows you to set the pen color.